# Simulating an enum type in Propel: error trying to generate form classes

Tags: symfony1, propel

```
documento: {type: varchar, sqltype: enum, size:
"'F','DDT','RC','FOURTH_ELEMENT','PM','KV','VN','CMS'", required:
true, defaultValue: 'F', required: true}
```

I get the next error message (always with the fourth element, I mean
if i write 3 or less elements it doesn't give any error):

> > > propel    generating form classes
>
> Cannot fetch TableMap for undefined
>   table: FOURTH_ELEMENT
>
> [?php
>
> /**  * sfGuardUserProfile form base
>   class.  *  * @method
>   sfGuardUserProfile getObject() Returns
>   the current form's model object  *  *
>   @package    ##PROJECT_NAME##  *
>   @subpackage form  * @author
>   AUTHOR_NAME  * @version    SVN: $Id: sfPropelFormGeneratedTemplate.php
>   24171 2009-11-19 16:37:50Z
>   Kris.Wallsmith $  */ abstract class
>   BasesfGuardUserProfileForm extends
>   BaseFormPropel {   public function
>   setup()   {
>       $this->setWidgets(array(

sf 1.4.

Javier

Comment: It's probably because of "_" character. I'm not sure if it can be fixed.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not the solution.

Comment: Check out this thread: http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/t/18732/

Comment: FYI: if you can wait (and upgrade) Propel 1.6 will have enum as advanced column type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should upgrade to Propel 1.6.3 in order to get the advanced columns feature (ENUM for instance): http://www.propelorm.org/cookbook/working-with-advanced-column-types.html#enum_columns.

William